# Vue.js Multiselect component error : Property or method "isOpen" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, error-handling, vue-composition-api, vue-multiselect

I'm facing with a common vue error but I can't find any solution to fix it.
I'm calling a [Multiselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/v1/index.html) component and I get lot of errors :

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "isOpen" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render....
Property or method "tabindex" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render...
Property or method "handleInputMousedown" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render...
Property or method "open" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render...
```

I imported and  my component :

```
import Multiselect from '@vueform/multiselect/dist/multiselect.vue2.js'
import '@vueform/multiselect/themes/default.css'
```

and I added in my components:

```
components: {
    Multiselect
},
```

Then I called it :

```
<Multiselect
   v-model="datas.phase.data"
   :options="datas.phase.items"
/>
```

I checked all my datas variables and there is no error.

I can't figured out why I get all these errors.
IMPORTANT : same calls in other components work fine.

Comment: I hadn't heard of this, so I did a quick search and found the GitHub repository.  The documentation shows the import  as ```import Multiselect from '@vueform/multiselect'```, which does not match what you have.  Maybe it doesn't matter, but might be worth taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

These errors occur when the *Vue 2 Composition API* plugin is not initialized in your app, as required by [the `@vueform/multiselect` docs](https://github.com/vueform/multiselect#using-with-vue-2).

To resolve the issue, ensure you've installed the plugin (e.g., in `main.js`):

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueCompositionAPI from '@vue/composition-api'

Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer !
Thank you for your help, it works !!